# Get Request Body works on some servers

Tags: get

Maybe this has been answered already and I can't find it.

But why do some servers allow a body to be sent with a GET request and others don't.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the answer I was looking for.

Simply put it means that the body should not effect the request.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/3279550